# Why is my ItemFileReadStore data attribute is null?

Tags: dojo

I am using Dojo 1.10 to create an ItemFileReadStore object using AMD. Though the console did not report any error while creating the store, I could see from the debugger that the store.data is null. I tried the same code on my browser console (both chrome and firefox) but there too its the same issue (store data is null). Could someone please help me figure out if am I missing something?

```
    require(["dojo/ready",
        "dojo/on",
        "dijit/registry",
        "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore"
    ], function(ready, on, registry, ItemFileReadStore) {

        var resultTablecolumns = [{
            label: 'ID',
            attr: 'id',
            sortable: true,
            sorted: 'ascending',
            width: 60,
            vAlignment: "middle",
            alignment: "right"
        }, {
            label: 'Hop',
            attr: 'hop',
            sortable: true,
            sorted: 'ascending',
            width: 100,
            vAlignment: "middle",
            alignment: "right"
        }, {
            label: 'Role',
            attr: 'role',
            sortable: true,
            sorted: 'ascending',
            width: 100,
            vAlignment: "middle",
            alignment: "right"
        }, {
            label: 'Status',
            attr: 'status',
            sortable: true,
            sorted: 'ascending',
            width: 100,
            vAlignment: "middle",
            alignment: "right"
        }];

        var storeItems = {
            "identifier": "id",
            "items": [{
                "id": "1",
                "hop": "first",
                "role": "classification",
                "status": ""
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "hop": "second",
                "role": "propagation",
                "status": "info"
            }, {
                "id": "3",
                "hop": "third",
                "role": "propagation",
                "status": "warning"
            }, {
                "id": "4",
                "hop": "fourth",
                "role": "propagation",
                "status": "error"
            }, {
                "id": "5",
                "hop": "fifth",
                "role": "enforcement",
                "status": ""
            }]
        };

        var resultTableStore = new ItemFileReadStore({
            data: storeItems
        });
        console.log("resultTableStore === ", resultTableStore);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your HTML?

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/40ad6zyt/2/).

```
require(["dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore","dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ItemFileReadStore, dom ){
    var storeItems = {
            "identifier": "id",
            "items": [{
                "id": "1",
                "hop": "first",
                "role": "classification",
                "status": ""
            }]
       };
    var store = new ItemFileReadStore({data: storeItems});
    console.log("ItemFileReadStore",ItemFileReadStore);
    dom.byId('store').innerHTML =   store  ;

});
```

There is a new kid on the block which replaces the above store i.e [dstore](http://dstorejs.io/). Try it.

Comment: Thank you Frank for the response. As I noted in my response I could figure out the issue with the help of a co-worker and have posted the answer above. I will sure try out the dstorejs you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out with the help of a co-worker. 
I am actually creating a ItemFileReadStore and using it in constructing a data-grid. The grid was not showing up because its parent was hid when it got created, and hence got its width set to zero. 
I understood from him that the data argument is processed on first fetch and used to populate internal structures.  It is then nulled out as it is no longer used.

So in this case, what was happening is ItemFileReadStore's data argument was processed on first-fetch while creating the grid and then got set to null.